# mac, osx, and osx-lion tags

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems that these tags are used very often to refer to the same thing (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/373977/typinator-has-a-funny-icon-with-two-dots-and-is-not-working-how-do-i-fix-this)). In fact (unless I read the search results wrong) there are 1,860 questions that use both [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx), and 212 that use both [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [osx-lion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-lion).

Is there a way to stop people from automatically using these tags together, provide some kind of warning, something?

As it is, the [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) tag is pretty clear. It relates to hardware. It is just that people seem to be ignoring the wiki.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using both `osx` and `osx-lion`. I sometimes add `osx` to more specifically tagged questions, since users rarely know whether their question applies more broadly. I keep their original tag in, so no information is lost.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to stop people from automatically using these tags together, provide some kind of warning, something?

Not currently. If using two tags together leads to ambiguous tagging or is otherwise very bad, I'd maybe write a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to address this and point out why it would be useful to have.

---

> As it is, the [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) tag is pretty clear. It relates to hardware. It is just that people seem to be ignoring the wiki.

Yes. As far as I can tell, most users don't read the tag wiki excerpt anyway. It's right there:

[image]

It's good we already have the MAC address confusion in there, but I don't see a way to fit another sentence like "Use the osx tag for questions about the operating system". That would be too much clutter.

We can't cover any possible case of confusion, and even the way Apple sells their products is ambiguous with regards to how they use the term "Mac". Then there's Microsoft. They only sell "Mac" products like [office-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-for-mac) and not "Office for OS X".

That being said, I don't think it's a huge problem to have [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) together. I believe that anybody who is interested in Apple questions on Super User will favorite both tags, since with Apple products that are on-topic here (i.e. Macs), using OS X is almost exclusively implied.

However, if you see a post where the usage is wrong, I think the best we can do is to remove the tag, replace it with [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) if necessary, and leave a custom message. If (and only if) you do this, the user will be informed of the edit. Sooner or later, they will probably learn.

> [image]

Comment: Edits are pretty difficult to notice, the messages even more so. Wouldn't an additional comment help, especially with users who just don't get it?

Comment: @DanielBeck If you use a custom edit message, the other user should get the notification bar (the yellow one) telling them about a new response. But yeah, if you see somebody do it repeatedly, I'd drop a comment.

Comment: What about for [tag:osx] and [tag:osx-lion]? Is there ever a case where both should be used?

Comment: @soandos If you're not sure if something is specific to only Lion, I'd use both. I'd always prefer the more specific tag though.