# Block the [hp] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [hp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hp) tag has been [removed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3948/company-tag-necromancy-the-zombie-apocalypse) [repeatedly](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again) as a generic company tag.

Since the previous major effort to clear out the company tags, this tag has been recreated and removed again [four additional times](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/revision/1077518/1331189/how-many-times-has-the-tag-been-added-removed?tagname=hp), three of which were in the current year, and the last of which was this April. Since then, it has been recreated ***again***, and currently has 37 questions.

Can we please block this tag from being reused? The SE team [has granted tag blocking requests in the past](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12759/blacklist-google) for similar tags, and blocking the tag is as simple as an SE team member adding it to the block list entries for the site. Also, tags that already exist *can* be blocked - it will prevent future uses of the tag, making it easier for the community to remove it.

Comment: It's easier just to flag it in the tag description and nuke it as you find it.

Comment: @Burgi But having to do that repeatedly so many times is a big pain. There's also no way to be notified when a tag is recreated (watcher lists are cleared when a tag is removed), so only when someone checks infrequently and notices will it get cleared, and in the meantime, it will continue to be used on other questions by others (who may not read the description) and increase the effort (and home page impact) required to remove the tag. A similar situation happened with the [tag:google] tag, and it was blacklisted for this same reason.

Answer (score 3):

I went through and tidied up all the questions with this tag. There were only 30 or so, it took about an hour all together.

Perhaps a better mechanism would be for newly created tags to be reviewed by the community before they are displayed on the question, this would solve the issue without resorting to strongarm tactics.

Comment: Yeah, I did [make a request several years ago](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8149/raise-the-minimum-rep-needed-to-create-new-tags) to have the required reputation to create tags raised, but that was de-facto declined.